# Data fetching, Post filtering and SWR in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am new to NextJs. On my blog page I use useSWR to show a list of blog items. I also have a dropdown with some values I use to filter the blog posts via a function like so,

```
const filterPosts = async (category)=>{
    let resp = await fetch(`${fetch_url}?category=${category}`)
    let data = await resp.json()

    setBlogItems(data.blog_posts)
    setNextPgLink(typeof data.next_pg_link !== 'undefined' ? data.next_pg_link : null)

    router.push(`/blog?category=${category}`, undefined, { shallow: true })
}
```

The filtering works fine but I realised the following issues:

1. When I go to another tab and go back to my NextJs website tab, the filtered posts go back to all the blog posts.
2. After the filtering the post and click on the Blog link in the navigation bar, the filtered blog posts still remain on the page instead of showing the list of blogs posts.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Please include the rest of the component where `useSWR` is used.